# Joint probability problem

Tags: probability

Consider an urn with 20 balls: 2 red and 18 blue.
The balls are being removed without replacement, until the two red balls are removed.
Let $X$ be the case the first red ball was removed, $Y$ the case where the second red ball was removed.

Find the joint probability function of $X$ and $Y$.

I know that the answer is $P\{X,Y\}=\frac{1}{{20 \choose 2}}; 1⩽X<Y⩽20$

We can easily understand that ${20 \choose 2}$ is about choosing 2 red balls out of 20. Now, I can't understand why its numerator is 1 and not ${20 \choose 1}⋅{19 \choose 1}$, that is choosing the first and the second red balls. I know that it sounds like an easy problem, but I couldn't find similar solved exercises for reference.

Comment: $P(X=x,Y=y)$ must be calculated for **fixed** $x,y$ so by determining the probability mass function the occurrence of first and second red ball are chosen already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task of removing the balls without replacement and noting the draw numbers of both red balls is equivalent to the task of unbiasedly selecting two places for the red balls in a line of twenty positions.

You want the probability that the *two* red balls occur in the *two* specified positions when selecting from *twenty* positions for them without bias. $$\mathsf P(X\,{=}\,x,Y\,{=}\,y) = \dfrac{\dbinom 22}{\dbinom {20}2}\cdot\mathbf 1_{1\leq x< y\leq 20}$$

Answer (score 0):

In general if random variable $Z$ has discrete uniform probability distribution on a finite set $S$ containing $n$ elements then: $$P(Z=z)=\frac1n\text{ for every }z\in S$$

Random pair $(X,Y)$ has discrete uniform probability distribution on the set: $$T:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb Z^2\mid 1\leq x<y\leq 20\}$$ and this set contains $\binom{20}2$ elements, so:$$P(X=x,Y=y)=\frac1{\binom{20}2}\text{ for every }(x,y)\in T$$

Observe that summation of these probabilities yields $1$, as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Write down the colours of all 20 balls in the order they appear. You get something like BBBBRBBBBBRBBBBBBBBB, and the sequence uniquely determines the values of $X$ and $Y$. We have $X=5, Y=11$ in this particular example. All such sequences are equally probable, and there are $\binom{20}{2}$ such sequences that prove the result that the probability is equal to $\frac{1}{\binom{20}{2}}$.